# Can Android Pay be disabled in-app?

Tags: android, nfc, android-pay, hce

I am looking for a way to suppress Android Pay app for one activity. iOS has [requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppressionWithResponseHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617078-requestautomaticpasspresentation?language=objc) method, which allows exactly this - suppressing Apple Pay while the app is in the foreground - I am trying to achieve this on Android.

I have implemented [foreground dispatch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch). This works fine for most NFC tags - tag gets detected in the activity and then is ignored. However, when contactless payment machine is detected, Android Pay app gets triggered instead and I never get onNewIntent call in my activity.

Other than implementing the app to do [card emulation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html) and ignoring these requests, which is not really an option for a few reasons, is there anything else I could do to suppress Android Pay? (and other similar payment apps with focus on Android Pay as most popular)

Comment: Have you tried reader-mode (`enableReaderMode()`)?

Comment: Just tried it, needed to add flags for NFC type, but it works now! :) Thank you. Completely missed that in the documentation, it's not even mentioned other than in the javadoc.

Comment: Did you find a way how to implement suppressing the payment apps?

Comment: @AlexAymkin The answer using `enableReaderMode` worked for me at the time, but I haven't worked with this for several years, so not sure if anything changed since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android 4.4 and above, you could use the reader-mode API to explicitly switch the device into reader/writer mode for a specific tag technology. This would disable the other NFC modes (peer-to-peer mode ("Android Beam") and card emulation mode).

```
nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, new NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback() {
    public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) { }
}, NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A | NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK, null);
```

Since you also want to ignore discovered tags, you could then simply drop (ignore) the tag handle received through the `onTagDiscovered()`.